# Why do we use @Embeddable In Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What's the use of `@Embedded` and `@Embeddable` In Hibernate ? Because every example i found on internet is inserting data inside of a single table and to do that using two different class. My point is if I am using a single table then I can map all the columns inside of a single class then why should i use different class. and if We use two different table then there is `one-to-one` and `one-to-many` hibernate relationship.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

There are two types of objects in Hibernate
1. Value Object
2. Entities

**Value Objects** are the objects which can not stand alone. Take `Address`, for example. If you say address, people will ask whose address is this. So it can not stand alone.

**Entity Objects** are those who can stand alone like `College` and `Student`.

So in case of value objects preferred way is to Embed them into an entity object.

To answer why we are creating two different classes: first of all, it's a OOPS concept that you should have loose coupling and high cohesion among classes. That means you should create classes for specialized purpose only. For example, your `Student` class should only have the info related to `Student`.

Second point is that by creating different classes you promote re-usability.

**When we define the value object for the entity class we use `@Embeddable`.

When we use value type object in entity class we use `@Embedded`**

Comment: now I understand the logic for creating two different class, I was thinking Embedded and Embeddable is only applied for a single table? or it can be used for multiple tables

Comment: I have never tried but I believe we can use, as I cannot see any direct harm into it

Comment: Dependancy on other objects is only an indicator not an evidence. For example Addresses could be reused and modeled as entitys or compositions/aggregations in general.

Comment: Is it `value` or `entity` if a class implements `org.hibernate.usertype.UserType` with two `String` fields?

Comment: @macemers An attribute using a custom UserType would be considered a value type, specifically a "basic" type. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#categorization-value

Comment: Can an Entity be embedded in another Entity?

Answer (score 5):

suppose we have employee table annotated with @entity and employee has Address so here i dont want to create two tables i.e employee and address, i just want create only one table i.e employee not Address table then we need to declare Address instance in Employee and add @embedable annotation on top of Address class, so finally we get table employee with its record and address records as well in single employee table

Answer (score 0):

This method is only for coordinating the difference between the business layer and the database

Answer (score -1):

One entity can be embedded in another entity. The attributes of an entity can be common attributes of more than one entity. In this case there can be one embeddable entity. And this embeddable entity can be embedded in more than one entity.

Let's consider an example. We have one `Animal` entity, which has `name` and `location` attributes. Now two different entities `Lion` and `Elephant` can have `Animal` attributes just by embedding the `Animal` entity. We can override the attributes. In `Animal` entity there is `location` attribute and in `Elephant` there is `place` attribute. So with the help of `@AttributeOverrides` we can do like below:

```
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "location", column = @Column(name = "place")) })
```

Comment: This seems like a paraphase of https://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/example-embeddable-embedded-hibernate-annotation. If yes, I think you should add a reference to that article or somehow mark it as a quotation.