# Hibernate: ManyToMany with extra columns not creating association

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I am following guide in order to create a many-to-many association between my two classes **Doctor** and **Table**. I want the associated table to have extra columns, so I needed to do the following steps according to the tutorial.

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

However, now when I run my code to create the association, nothing is created in the database.

Here is my code

**Doctor**

```
package edu.cs157b.hibernate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="DOCTOR_INFO")
@NamedQueries (
    {
        @NamedQuery(name = "Doctor.getAll", query = "from Doctor"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Doctor.findByName", query = "from Doctor where name = :name")
    }
)
public class Doctor implements Person {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Specialty specialty;
    private List<AppointmentRequest> appointmentRequests = new ArrayList<AppointmentRequest>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(unique=true)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.PERSIST) 
    @JoinColumn(name="specialty_id") 
    public Specialty getSpecialty() {
        return specialty;
    }

    public void setSpecialty(Specialty specialty) {
        this.specialty = specialty;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.doctor")
    public List<AppointmentRequest> getAppointmentRequests() {
        return this.appointmentRequests;
    }

    public void setAppointmentRequests(List<AppointmentRequest> appointmentRequests) {
        this.appointmentRequests = appointmentRequests;
    }

    @Transient
    public List<Patient> getPatients() {
        List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<Patient>();

        for(AppointmentRequest appointment:appointmentRequests) {
            patients.add(appointment.getPatient());
        }
        return patients;
    }
}
```

**Patient**

```
package edu.cs157b.hibernate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="PATIENT_INFO")
@NamedQueries (
    {
        @NamedQuery(name = "Patient.getAll", query = "from Patient"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Patient.findByName", query = "from Patient where name = :name")
    }
)
public class Patient implements Person {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String medical_record;
    private List<AppointmentRequest> appointmentRequests = new ArrayList<AppointmentRequest>();

    public String getMedical_record() {
        return medical_record;
    }

    public void setMedical_record(String medical_record) {
        this.medical_record = medical_record;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(unique=true)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.patient", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<AppointmentRequest> getAppointmentRequests() {
        return this.appointmentRequests;
    }

    public void setAppointmentRequests(List<AppointmentRequest> appointmentRequests) {
        this.appointmentRequests = appointmentRequests;
    }

    @Transient
    public List<Doctor> getDoctors() {
        List<Doctor> doctors = new ArrayList<Doctor>();

        for(AppointmentRequest appointment:appointmentRequests) {
            doctors.add(appointment.getDoctor());
        }
        return doctors;
    }
}
```

**AppointmentRequest**

```
package edu.cs157b.hibernate;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.AssociationOverride;
import javax.persistence.AssociationOverrides;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "APPOINTMENT_REQUEST")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.patient", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PATIENT_ID")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.doctor", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "DOCTOR_ID")) })
public class AppointmentRequest implements java.io.Serializable {

    private AppointmentRequestId pk = new AppointmentRequestId();
    private Date appointmentDate;
    private boolean fulfilled;

    public AppointmentRequest() {
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public AppointmentRequestId getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(AppointmentRequestId pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public Patient getPatient() {
        return getPk().getPatient();
    }

    public void setPatient(Patient patient) {
        getPk().setPatient(patient);
    }

    @Transient
    public Doctor getDoctor() {
        return getPk().getDoctor();
    }

    public void setDoctor(Doctor doctor) {
        getPk().setDoctor(doctor);
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "APPOINTMENT_DATE", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public Date getAppointmentDate() {
        return this.appointmentDate;
    }

    public void setAppointmentDate(Date appointmentDate) {
        this.appointmentDate = appointmentDate;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        AppointmentRequest that = (AppointmentRequest) o;

        if (getPk() != null ? !getPk().equals(that.getPk())
                : that.getPk() != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public boolean isFulfilled() {
        return fulfilled;
    }

    public void setFulfilled(boolean fulfilled) {
        this.fulfilled = fulfilled;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return (getPk() != null ? getPk().hashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

**AppointmentRequestId**

```
package edu.cs157b.hibernate;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Embeddable
public class AppointmentRequestId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Patient patient;
    private Doctor doctor;

    @ManyToOne
    public Patient getPatient() {
        return patient;
    }

    public void setPatient(Patient patient) {
        this.patient = patient;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Doctor getDoctor() {
        return doctor;
    }

    public void setDoctor(Doctor doctor) {
        this.doctor = doctor;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        AppointmentRequestId that = (AppointmentRequestId) o;

        if (patient != null ? !patient.equals(that.patient) : that.patient != null) return false;
        if (doctor != null ? !doctor.equals(that.doctor) : that.doctor != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = (patient != null ? patient.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (doctor != null ? doctor.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

}
```

**Code to create association**

```
public AppointmentRequest createAppointment(Patient patient, Doctor doctor) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    AppointmentRequest appointment = new AppointmentRequest();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        if(patient == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        if(doctor == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        appointment.setPatient(patient);
        appointment.setDoctor(doctor);
        appointment.setFulfilled(true);

        patient.getAppointmentRequests().add(appointment);
        doctor.getAppointmentRequests().add(appointment);

        session.save(appointment);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    finally {
            session.close();
    }
    return appointment;         
}
```

Also is there a better way to get access the many-to-many relationship than having to create your own custom method for getting a **Patient's** ***Doctors*** through the **AppointmentRequest** table.

Comment: post your `hibernate.cfg.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to promote your AppointmentRequest object to an Entity and save the patient and doctor objects (cascading the associations will save the Appointment Request in the same transaction).
Since you did not save the patient or the doctor nothing actually got saved.

Here is an answer that explains clearly the difference between embedded objects and entities.

[Why do we use @Embeddable In Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341838/why-should-we-use-embeddable-in-hibernate)

Because appointment request carries other information besides just mapping an association between Patient and Doctor it deserves to be an entity.