# How to perist a new entity with existing @OneToOne relation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    private ProductDescription description;
}
```

I'm using `spring-data-jpa` and  `CrudRespository.save()` to persist entities.

Problem: `@OneToOne` entities won't get merged if I save them and they already exists by id.
I assumed this would just work, because the save method from spring is as follows:

```
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

So I thought the complete entity would just be merged.

```
@Entity
public class ProductDescription {
    @Id
    private int productId; //set by code, not autogenerated by db
    private String text;
}

product = new Product();
description = new ProductDescription();
description.setProductId(123); //assume this id already exists in db
product.setProductDescription(description);
```

Result: `productId "123" already exists`.

How would I have to do this?

Or moreover: would you think it *should* work this way due to the cascade? Or did I misunderstand the mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

to merge the entity you will have to use bidirectional @OneToOne.

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH}, mappedBy="parentProduct")
    private ProductDescription description;
}

@Entity
public class ProductDescription {
    @OneToOne
    private Product parentProduct;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this possible without bidirectional? Because I want to use the `ProductDescription` to different entities in a `@OneToOne` mapping, so I won't be willing to introduce an additional class for each one.

Comment: In this case this is a `@ManyToOne` not `@OneToOne`. And that really simplifies everything

Comment: No, I don't want to assign the *same* `ProductDescription` to multiple parent objects. Just I want to have multiple parent entities that all use a single `@OneToOne` relation to the `ProductDescription`. But each parent will only always have one single `ProductDescription`.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341838/why-should-we-use-embeddable-in-hibernate

Comment: Unfortunately not: an `@Embeddable` entity will result in a single table for bnoth entities. I have to move all `ProductDescription`s in a single table, and all products in a different table.

Comment: but how do you save @OneToOne? It should also be saved in a separate table

Comment: Yes, I need one table for `products` and a 2nd table for `ProductDescription`. That's what `@OneToOne` achieves.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87229/discussion-between-funtik-and-membersound).