# Hibernate two parents one child mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, entity

I have following scenario: There are companies and employees. Each company has a set of employees. Each employee can work for several companies. So I implemented following relationships:

Company.class:

```
@JoinTable(name = "company_employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") )
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Employee> employees;
```

Employee.class:

```
@JoinTable(name = "company_employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id") )
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Company> companies;
```

Obviously, to work for several companies, each employee should have several not overlapping schedules assigned for each company he or she works.
Also, there should be a list of schedules for each combination Company-Employee, as sometimes old schedule expires, and new schedule becomes effective.
So I also have `Schedule.class`, which is supposed to have `child to parent @ManyToOne` relationships both to `Company` and `Employee`, and should work following way: each `Schedule`, and thus, `List<Schedule>` should correspond to exactly one combination of `Company` and `Employee` instances.
How to implement this relationship?

**Update 1**

I only have in mind adding `@OneToMany Schedule` relationship to each `Company` and `Employee`, but then I need to put instances of `Schedule` both to `Company` and `Employee` each time, and this way just don't look right, also it's not obvious for me now how to fetch it back.
So any help will be appreciated.

---

This post was updated to show real-life scenario I have, not just generic Entity1, Entity2, Entity3 names for classes.

**Update 2**

I accepted the answer, but I cannot use it if Schedule contain Lists.
According to my plan, `Schedule` should contain `List<Vacation>` to know the set of `Vacations` over a year, and `List` of `Days`, each of which shows start of particular week day, break, and end of this day. Those `Days` are also unique for each `Schedule` instance.

It was supposed to be something like below, but obviously now I don't have `schedule_id`, so how to connect those lists to `Schedule`?

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) 
@JoinColumn(name = "schedule_id") 
private List<Vacation> vacations;

@JoinTable(name = "schedule_week", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "schedule_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "day_id") )
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) 
private List<Day> week;
```

How to include those lists right?

Comment: It would be better if you add the real scenario. The solution may not be related to hibernate, but a design change.

Comment: @tharindu_DG I edited my post to show real scenario. Probably you are right, hope it makes things more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest the following solution.

An `embeddable` class that contains the `Company` and `Employee` for a particular schedule.

```
@Embeddable
public class ScheduleOwner implements Serializable{

    @MapsId("id")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Company c;

    @MapsId("id")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Employee e;
}
```

The `Schedule` class is embedding a `ScheduleOwner` instance.

```
@Entity
public class Schedule {

    @EmbeddedId
    ScheduleOwner owner;

    String description;
}
```

The `Company` and `Employee` classes(no change done to them)

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @JoinTable(name = "company_employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") )
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Employee> employees;
}


@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @JoinTable(name = "company_employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id") )
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Company> companies;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Below is how you could save and fetch results.

```
  Employee e1 = new Employee();
  Company c1 = new Company();
  c1.employees.add(e1);

  e1.companies.add(c1);

  ScheduleOwner so = new ScheduleOwner();
  so.c = c1;
  so.e = e1;

  Schedule s = new Schedule();
  s.owner = so;

  session.save(c1);
  session.save(e1);
  session.save(s);

  // below query will fetch from schedule, where company id = 9
  Schedule ss = (Schedule) session.createQuery("From Schedule sh where sh.owner.c.id = 9").uniqueResult();
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @JoinTable(name = "company_employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName="id") 
                                        , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    String name;
}

@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "employees")
    List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<>();

    String name;
}

@Entity
public class Schedule {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int schedule_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Company company;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Employee employee;

    String description;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "schedule")
    List<Vacation> vacations;

}

@Entity
public class Vacation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int vacation_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "schedule_id" ) 
    Schedule schedule;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vacation")
    List<Day> days;
}
```

`Day` entity directly relates to `Vacation`. Not to `Schedule`.

```
@Entity
public class Day {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vacation_id")
    Vacation vacation;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great effort to help! I have never used `@Embedded` feature. Could you explain further, how it should work in Java? Is following sequence of actions right? to set: instantiate `Schedule`, instantiate `ScheduleOwner` (it should not have it's own table in the db, as I understand), fetch `Company` and `Employee` from db, set `Company` and `Employee` to `ScheduleOwner`, set `ScheduleOwner` to `Schedule`, store `Schedule` to db. To fetch `schedule` by `employee_id` and `company_id` - I don't understand now... how this part should be done? Also be affected other app structure?

Comment: Also, if to do this way, why not to put `Employee` and `Company` to `Schedule` directly with `@ManyToOne` relationship (many `Schedule` to one `Employee` and to one `Company`), without this intermediate `ScheduleOwner` class?

Comment: @Battle_Slug: I changed the design and updated my answer. please check.  Read this for more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341838/why-should-we-use-embeddable-in-hibernate

Comment: Thanks for that. Looks great, but I've read about `@Embeddable` and I see, that it is supposed to separate some common part of several entities in one class, like usual OOP pattern. But here you do something different: you just use it to have in Schedule only one foreign key `owner` instead of two foreign keys `company_id` and `employee_id` (like if I just put `company` and `employee` directly to `schedule`). Am I right or is there some other thoughts behind your implementation?

Comment: This solution will create only 3 tables. Customer, Employee and Schedule.
Schedule table will have customer id, employee id and other schedule attributes. 
Schedule table will have a composite primary key which contains employee id and company id. (means there can be only one schedule for a given company id and a employee id)

Comment: `ScheduleOwner` is not an entity and it will not create a separate table. Try running the code.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was sleeping, probably we are in different time zones )

Comment: @Battle_Slug : Yeah... :-)

Comment: Sorry, it seems I am not able to use it this way. My `Schedule` contains also fields:  `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
 @JoinColumn(name = "schedule_id")
 private List<Vacation> vacations;` and another one:
 `@JoinTable(name = "schedule_week", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "schedule_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "day_id") )
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
 private List<Day> week;` How to change it than to be able to contain lists of other entities?

Comment: @Battle_Slug: I'm not clear about the requirement. can you update the question with your full requirement?

Comment: I updated, please kindly check whether it's clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: @Battle_Slug: I have updated my answer as I understood the question.

Comment: Thanks, will do this way. It really helps a lot, both to my project and my understanding.