# Can I access root Entity from embedded?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Is it possible to access root Entity from Embedded object? 
My goal is to extract a big class into small one, any alternative to Embedded object would do.

```
@Entity
public class Address{
  @Embedded
  private City city;
}

public class City{
   private Address address; // I would like to access Address here
}
```

Got error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for Address in City
```

Comment: Why would you want that? Your current structure would be a `@OneToOne` mapping, but that is not the sense of `Embedded` classes

Comment: I just over simplified my example, so I can easily communicate my question, hope this is ok.

Comment: I'd say that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19341862/7109162) should tell you what exactly `Embedded` classes are and why you use them. Hopefully you then understand that what you want to do is senseless with `Embedded` classes. If you still want to do it, then you have to change your mapping

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible, because embedable objects is part of root entity in db. They stored in same table. You can set it manually after select, or use root entity in your code and get `city` through root entity. if you want have link to `Address` from city then make `City` as entity with bidirectional relation

**UPD**

You can use `@Parent` annotation in your embeddable objects. It's hibernate annotation