# Hibernate : for a single table group attributes into a subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, relational-database

I want to do :

```
create table user (
    id bigint primary key auto_increment,
    firstname varchar(128),
    lastname varchar(128),
    street varchar(128),
    zipcode mediumint,
    city varchar(128)
)
```

then :

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private Address address; // Here I want an Address rather than street, zip, and city directly inside User

    ...

}
```

and :

```
public class Address {

    private String street;

    private Integer zipcode;

    private String city;

    ...

}
```

(that is an example)

How to do that with Hibernate ? @OneToOne ? The problem seems simple and since I can't find the solution around here, it must be obvious.

Comment: Look at embeddable type:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341838/why-do-we-use-embeddable-in-hibernate

Answer (score 2):

First, annotate your `Address` class with `@Embeddable`:

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    /*class definition here*/
    ...
}
```

And then update your user class in this way:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    @Embedded
    private Address address; 

    ...

}
```

That's it. If you want a more complex example look [here](https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-embeddable-demo/). Just pay attention to model classes definition, it makes no difference if you are using Spring Boot or not as long as you handle your database with JPA.

Comment: Thanks it seems great. I will accept it when I can test it since some work needs to be done before that.

Answer (score -1):

You can associate entities through a one-to-one relationship using @OneToOne annotation.

```
  @Entity
  public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Address address; 

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Address getAddress()
    {
     return address;
    }
  }
```

Reference:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association